# PDFBOX: How to write bold and italic text no matter the font

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working with PDFBox 2.0.27, using the PDPageContentStream class to write some text at a given (x,y) position on a page of the document.  The font of the text is represented using the PDType0Font class and it is loaded from a .ttf file provided by the user.

The code is (mostly) as follows:

```
try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, document.getPage(page), PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false, false)){
    PDType0Font font = load(document, pathToTtf)
    contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
    if (isBoldFont){
        // logic goes here
    }
    if (isItalicFont){
        // logic goes here
    }
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
    contentStream.showText(text);
    contentStream.endText();
}
```

The problem comes when I have to style the text in order to make it look bold or/and italic as it is to my understanding that PDFBox is quite a low level library, unlike its counterpart iText when it is possible to delegate such task to the library.

For the bold text case I tried with `contentStream.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.FILL_STROKE);` and it kind of does the trick but it is quite illegible when the font size is rather small so im wondering if there is a better way to do this.

For the italic text case I was suggested to apply some kind of skew transformation to the content stream but everything I tried seems to not only tilt the text to the right but also move it's x position to the right.

I understand that the bold and/or italic variations of the font should be loaded using different .ttf files but since I am translating code currently written in iText, I need a workaround that allows the user to not have to load multiple .ttf files, just the one of the "main" font.

Comment: The Bold and Italic fonts will be from different .ttf files.

Comment: You are correct in that this is the proper way to use a bold and/or italic variation of a font but I am currently looking for a workaround in order to not bother the end user since this functionality was written in iText where doing that is not required.

Comment: Concerning poor man's bold (with `RenderingMode.FILL_STROKE`) - if you set the current line width together with the font size, e.g. to a tenth of it, you won't have those issues for small fonts. Concerning poor man's italics (using skew transformations) - you give too little information on how you tried that, so it's hard to tell how to improve your code.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment solved my issue regarding bold text. Could I bother you with an example on how to implement "poor man's italics"? I tired a lot of things but nothing worked. My general idea was to use the transform method of the PDPageContentStream class to concatenate the (0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) matrix to the current transformation matrix